# running Google Charts with JavaScript in gwt HTMLPanel

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-visualization

I am trying to run a test chart from google chart example in a HTML Panel located in the middle of my webpage. There is a lot of customization that I would like to do with the chart, which is why I do not want to use any type of api derived from the google charts. I want to simple run the javascript in a HTMLPanel. Here is what I tried.

```
public class TwitterTimeSeries implements EntryPoint 
{


public void onModuleLoad() {

Element script2 = DOM.createElement("script");
DOM.setElementAttribute(script2,"language","text/javascript");
DOM.setElementAttribute(script2,"src","https://www.google.com/jsapi");
    Element script = DOM.createElement("script");
    DOM.setElementAttribute(script,"language","text/javascript");
    script.setInnerText("google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages' ['corechart']});" 
+ "google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);" 
+ "function drawChart() {" 
+ "var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'], ['2004',  1000,      400], ['2005',  1170,      460], ['2006',  660,       1120], ['2007',  1030,      540]]);" 
+ "var options = {title: 'Company Performance'};" 
+ "var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));" 
+ "chart.draw(data, options); }" 

            );
    HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel("<div id=\"chart_div\"></div>");
    RootPanel.get().add(html);  
    DOM.appendChild(DOM.getElementById("chart_div"),script);

  }
};
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you shouldn't do this directly. You should use the [gwt-google-apis](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted?tm=6).

They have wrapper for most of the charts and you can easily write your own wrapper if you miss one.

Apart from that, it is good practice to write a wrapper/widget because they can be easily re-used in other projects.
If something is missing in the wrappers (for example some customization of the chart appearance) you can still rely on pure Javascript (JSNI) to implement it.

Code would look something like that:

```
public class TwitterTimeSeries implements EntryPoint 
{
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
                            dataTable.addColumns(ColumnType.String,"Year");
                            dataTable.addColumns(ColumnType.Number,"Sales");
                            dataTable.addColumns(ColumnType.Number,"Expenses");
                            dataTable.addRows(1)
                            dataTable.setValues(0,0,"2004");
                            dataTable.setValues(0,1,1000);
                            dataTable.setValues(0,2,400);
                            Options options = Options.create();
                            options.set("title","Company Performance");
                            LineChart chart = new LineChart(dataTable,options);
                            panel.add(chart);
                            RootPanel.get().add(panel);
            }
        }, CoreChart.PACKAGE, MotionChart.PACKAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am currently using gwt's wrapper. How do I implement pure javascript in addition to this wrapper. I am having hard time looking up this example.

Comment: just subclass the wrapper and add a method using [JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI).